# Unwanted spaces between div selectors after Zoom In in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, deployment

When I Zoom in the page in Chrome or Firefox there appear strange gaps between div selectors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlXy0.png)

When Zoom level is 100% everything is fine.

How to fix this?

I want to remove the gaps between the div tags when zoom level is >100 or < 100. Is there any special reason for thos

Comment: You need to include some of the code on here, we can't help unless you show us what you did.

Comment: It's a known phenomenon - a bit like a sort of rounding error when the system is trying to decide on how to map part CSS pixels to screen pixels. If you show us the relevant code there may be a workaround. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: FYI: You mean div _elements_, not "div selectors". (A selector is part of a CSS rule, that _selects_ elements based on certain criteria.)